# how to fetch multiple columns containing multiple values using a specific value from single table in PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php

I want to fetch multiple columns containing multiple values using a specific value from single table in PHP/MYSQL.

My table structure is like,

```
  id  | Name |  s_id   |
-----------------------------
  1   | aaa  | 3 10 13 | 
  2   | bbb  | 1 2 5 8 16 23 | 
  3   | ccc  | 1 3 11 19 25 | 
  4   | ddd  | 7 15 19 25 | 
  5   | eee  | 5 13 16 21 |
```

My query is,

```
"SELECT Name FROM table where s_id like '%1%'"
```

I should get the output as,

```
bbb
ccc
```

but i'm getting all the names whose 'id' has `'1'` in its value, `i.e. 1, 11, 19, 16, etc.` What should i change in my code and table structure? do i need to use any delimiter? am coding it in php.
pls help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `where s_id REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]'`

```
"SELECT Name FROM table where s_id REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]'"
```

Comment: Thank you Nikhil. I tried it, but am getting the following error. "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)"

Comment: Show your query what you try so far.

Comment: Your query is working fine. thank you. But if i want to pass a variable (dynamically) in my query what should i do.? pls help me out.

Comment: Try "SELECT Name FROM table where s_id REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$var."[[:>:]]'";

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing the data in the same way, just a space after the value you want to filter will work fine, Like this
"SELECT Name FROM table where s_id like '%1 %'"

Comment: Its working, but for few values its not working fine. values getting mismatch. Thank you for your answer Shyamala.